# Object spread operator in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I want to copy an object while changing only a single property. Without Flow, I could do this using the object spread operator like this:

```
class Point { x: number = 10; y: number = 10; }
const p1 = new Point();
const p2 = {...p1, y: 5};
```

But when I add type annotations to p1 and p2 like this:

```
const p1 = new Point();
const p2 = {...p1, y: 5};
```

I get the following error:

```
 11: const p2:Point = {...p1, y: 5};
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
 11: const p2:Point = {...p1, y: 5};
          ^^^^^ Point
```

How would I achieve this type of operation in a type safe way in Flow?

As an example, in Elm, I can do this:

```
p2 = { p1 | y = 5 }
```

There must be some equivalent in Flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you (really) need a `class` instead of a `type` alias you can simulate the Elm syntax `p2 = { p1 | y = 5 }` by defining a constructor with only one argument

```
export class Point {
  x: number = 10;
  y: number = 10;
  constructor(fields?: { x: number, y: number }) {
    Object.assign(this, fields)
  }
}
const p1 = new Point()
const p2: Point = new Point({...p1, y: 5})
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use object spread, you don't get an exact copy of an object. Instead, you get a plain object with all source object's properties copied. So, Flow is right here, `p2` is not `Point`. Try this instead:

```
type Point = { x: number, y: number };
const p1: Point = { x: 10, y: 10 };
const p2: Point = { ...p1, y: 5 };
```

Comment: So what would be the type safe Flow way to do this?

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't realize that what you were showing is to use a type instead of a class. That *does* answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Explanation: `class` does not work because it uses [nominal typing](https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4) but `type` works because that uses structural typing.