# What does spread operator in type declaration do in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

If I have two objects of partially matching shapes like

```
const point2d = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const point3d = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
```

then the valid type declaration in Flow would be

```
type Point2D = { x: number, y: number };
type Point3D = Point2D & { z: number };
```

At first, I tried to use the object spread operator and hit a problem quite soon because notation like

```
type Point3D = { ...Point2D, z: number };
```

is passed as valid but does not achieve the goal because in the end both `x` and `y` properties are missing from the `Point3D` type.

For example, I can do this with spread notation (which is wrong):

```
type Point2D = { x: number, y: number };
type Point3D = { ...Point2D, z: number };

const point2d: Point2D = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const point3d: Point3D = { y: 0, z: 0 }; // No errors
```

but cannot miss the `x` property in object declaration with type intersection notation:

```
type Point2D = { x: number, y: number };
type Point3D = Point2D & { z: number };

const point2d: Point2D = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const point3d: Point3D = { y: 0, z: 0 }; // Cannot assign object literal to `point3d` because property `x` is missing in object literal [1] but exists in `Point2D` [2].
```

Note that both cases are not exact shapes.

Is Flow's behavior in case of spread notation intentional in this case? Am I missing something?

Comment: _Not_ duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032532/object-spread-operator-in-flow).

Comment: Hmm, it definitely [should](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbAEwBEoF4oG8oAeAXFEgK4C2ARhAE4A0UIJ51dUAvgNwBQoksRCgDMmHPGRpMAMjxQAXi0o1anXjwDGcJAGdgUMELQATEhJQZsc4lAAMjZnbWbteg0eGnBk0Vfw37JhJAxSduHh5DH2MAOgJeAHoEqItY+S4oJKgAHgBaXKgyJC0KCggUKAAzOFU6WhqIoA) be doing what you're saying. What leads you to believe this is not the case?

Comment: For sure, but my problem isn’t in `point2d.z` but rather in `point3d.x`. And note that you use proper “&” notation in your example whereas my question is about spread operator within type declaration.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that, I sent you the wrong example. [Here's](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbAEwBEoF4oG8oAeAXFEgK4C2ARhAE4A0UIJ51dUAvgNwBQoksRCgDMmHPgB0U+MjTpGALxaUatTrx4BjOEgDOwKGCFoAJiRkoM2PIRIAGRsyh31WnfsPHhZwbNHX8YmdHe0V7Vx4jPxMJAl4AenioyxiFLihEqAAeAFocqDIkbQoKCBQoADM4NTpaap4eIA) the right one. The point here is that line 7 in this example would error if `x` was not included in the type `Point3D`.

Comment: Extended the question with two examples where I would expect identical behavior of Flow but it's different and I don't get why. So I found out that when I directly refer to a property of an object of type `Point3D`, and this type was declared in any of the two ways, Flow correctly warns about non-existing properties and such. But when I _declare_ an object, the two cases bring different results. I read through docs about exact object types, that's fine, but in my case the shapes aren't exact in both cases. I'm absolutely lost.

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3534).

The short version is that you can resolve basically all of these sorts of issues by making your objects exact. In general I've found that you'll have a much easier time with object types when making them exact as a rule unless you *really* don't want them to be exact for some reason. Also, `$ReadOnly` where applicable. [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbAEwBEoF4oG8A+UAHgFxRICuAtgEYQBOANFCGZbQ1PgL4DcAUKEixEKAMyYcBKADo58ZGnTMAXm2p16XPv34BjOEgDOwKGFFoAJmQUoM2PMTIAGZqyjOoOg8dPnFYtYiAZKO7q5Qah7MpB5evFAA9IlQAHJwUAz0cPRGQA)